# Correct work with exceptions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

For example, I have the following method:

```
        public void MeetingNoteSave(int MeetingID, string note, bool IsInviter, string Username)
        {
                meeting = Get<Meeting>(p => p.MeetingID == MeetingID && p.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName == Username);
                MeetingNoteSaveCheckings(meeting, MeetingID);
// some actions here
        }

        void MeetingNoteSaveCheckings(Meeting meeting, int MeetingID)
        {
            DateTime currentDateWithTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (meeting == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Meeting does not exist. MeetingID=" + MeetingID);
            }
            DateTime meetingTime = meeting.MeetingTime.Day.AddHours(meeting.MeetingTime.Hour).AddMinutes(meeting.MeetingTime.Minute);
            if (meetingTime > currentDateWithTime)
            {
                throw new Exception("Meeting is future. MeetingID=" + MeetingID + ". Meeting time = '" + meetingTime + "', Current time='" + currentDateWithTime + "'");
            }
        }
```

so, method can throw 2 exceptions - when meeting not exists with such parameters at all or when time of meeting more than current time (should be past or current).

Now, I'm writting Unit Tests. Simple method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MeetingNoteSave()
    {
        _repository.MeetingNoteSave(1, "My note", true, "xxx@xxx.com");
    }
```

Of course, call unit test will be fail with some parameters. I want to catch these cases, so, test should be success. I can do by 2 ways. First is simple, but a little dirty:

```
        try
        {
            _repository.MeetingNoteSave(1, "My note", true, "xxx@xxx.com");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.IndexOf("Meeting does not exist")>=0)
            {
                // some actions
            }

            if (ex.Message.IndexOf("Meeting is future")>=0)
            {
                // some actions
            }
        }
```

so, test will be success with incorrect input parameters (so, unit test can be used to test method with incorrect parameters), but fail with encountered errors. Good.

Other way - create special dummy exceptions like MeetingNullException and MeetingFutureException

```
public class MeetingNullException : Exception
{
}

public class MeetingFutureException : Exception
{
}
```

throw them and catch them. More correctly, but much more code. Dummy code.
Which way is more correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither, they're both flawed. Your second approach is in the right direction though: you should avoid throwing general exceptions of type `Exception`; specific subclasses are much more expressive.

What you have to do in your tests then is use the `[ExpectedException]` attribute which will make them look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MeetingNullException))]
public void MeetingNoteSave_WithNotExistingMeeting()
{
    _repository.MeetingNoteSave(1, "My note", true, "xxx@xxx.com");
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MeetingFutureException ))]
public void MeetingNoteSave_WithFutureDate()
{
    _repository.MeetingNoteSave(1, "My note", true, "xxx@xxx.com");
}
```

Make sure you only have one test for each possible flow of your program: 2 exceptions means 2 tests. Personally I might avoid creating the specific subclasses and just use `ArgumentException` but that's up to you to decide. If you have expressive test names and the code is sufficiently self documenting, you'll know what argument is being referred to anyway.

Comment: thank you. Also, can you show me your approach with ArgumentException?

Comment: It's exactly the same as above, only you use `[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]` and `throw new ArgumentException("meeting");`. What's import then is making it clear from the method's name: `SaveMeetingNote_WithNullMeeting_ThrowsArgumentException` and the arguments: `_repository.SaveMeetingNote(VALID_ID, INVALID_NAME, VALID_ISINVITED, VALID_EMAIL);` which are constants you define prior to that. Then there is no question about what you meant.